# Buscar o nome de uma estrada no Overpass API

Tags: api, script, geolocalização

Preciso de ajuda, quero saber como faço para obter os dados da rua(nome, tipo, endereço, etc.) através da Latitude e Longitude, utilizando a Overpass API, sou iniciante com ela e preciso muito desses dados.

Comment: O que você tentou até agora? Considere incluir o código que desenvolveu até então.

Comment: Eu consegui ontem gerar este código aqui na API Turbo do Overpass, mas eu queria um código mais próprio utilizando a linguagem normal do Overpass.
<osm-script output="json">
  <query type="way">
      <around lat="-27.773056" lon="-54.230312" radius="5"/>
      <has-kv k="highway"/>
  </query>
  <union>
    <item/>
    <recurse type="down"/>
  </union>
  <print/>
</osm-script>
@BrunoCésar